# Powershell outlook message parsing

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm wrote this script to look for NDR messages in Outlook.  I want to find these messages and parse the body of the message to extract the email address the message bounced back from.  Finding the messages with the subject is working fine.  The issue I'm having is the body of the NDR emails are garbled with strange characters so I cannot parse them.

Anyone know how I can get around this?

```
 $olFolderInbox = 6
 $outlook = new-object -com outlook.application;
 $ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
 $inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)
 $targetfolder = $inbox.Folders | ? { $_.name -eq "Dump" }

$targetfolder.items | % {

  if($_.subject -match "Undeliverable"){

    write-output $_.subject
    write-output $_.SentOnBehalfOfName
    write-output $_.body
 }

}
```

sample from

> $_.body

格浴㹬格慥㹤਍洼瑥⁡瑨灴攭畱癩∽潃瑮湥⵴祔数•潣瑮湥㵴琢硥⽴瑨汭※档牡敳㵴獵愭捳楩㸢⼼敨摡㰾潢祤ാ㰊㹰戼㰾潦瑮挠汯牯∽〣〰㘰∶猠穩㵥㌢•慦散∽牁慩≬䐾汥癩牥⁹慨⁳慦汩摥琠⁯桴獥⁥敲楣楰湥獴漠⁲牧畯獰㰺是湯㹴⼼㹢⼼㹰਍昼湯⁴潣潬㵲⌢〰〰〰•楳敺∽∲映捡㵥吢桡浯≡㰾㹰愼栠敲㵦洢楡瑬㩯湁牵条
                          䴮瑩慲牀换浣挮浯㸢湁牵条䴮瑩慲牀换浣挮浯⼼㹡戼㹲਍桔⁥ⵥ慭汩愠摤敲獳礠畯攠瑮牥摥挠畯摬❮⁴敢映畯摮‮汐慥敳挠敨正琠敨爠捥灩敩瑮猧攠洭楡⁬摡牤獥⁳œں⁤牴⁹潴爠獥湥⁤桴⁥”®«Aجُ⹥䤠⁦桴⁥ ¶³¶¾´⁭潣瑮湩敵ⱳ瀠敬獡⁥‌ک¬—¼ٌ⁴‌¨ا£–ك›D“µھ—⹫戼㹲਍⼼㹰਍瀼㰾⁡牨晥∽
                          慭汩潴䄺“³اأطرں¨کO䁮’Rµ·⹭潣≭䄾摮敲匮煥極䁮’Rµ·⹭潣㱭گè㰾ہخാ吊敨攠洭楡⁬摡牤獥⁳‌¨⁵œ£صûاأ⁤潣汵湤琧戠⁥ءتœ±⹤倠敬獡⁥µµ’ج⁫桴⁥اأé¹کKœ£❴⁳ⵥ慭汩愠摤敲獳愠摮琠祲琠⁯敲敳摮琠敨洠獥慳敧‮晉琠敨瀠潲汢浥挠湯楴畮獥‬汰慥敳挠湯慴瑣礠畯⁲”«ى
                          ل”¨ڑr㰮ہخാ㰊瀯ാ㰊㹰愼栠敲㵦›¥ک@¬–㩯±âکE‘]⹶獁橩䁡’Rµ·⹭潣≭䄾桢湩癡䄮کM‘Y —»»ن½’«ن´⼼㹡‘ù㹲਍桔⁥ⵥ慭汩愠摤敲獳礠畯攠瑮牥摥挠畯摬❮⁴敢映畯摮‮汐慥敳挠敨正琠敨爠捥灩敩瑮猧攠洭楡⁬摡牤獥⁳œں⁤牴⁹潴爠獥湥⁤桴⁥”®«Aجُ⹥䤠⁦桴⁥ 
                          ¶³¶¾´⁭潣瑮湩敵ⱳ瀠敬獡⁥‌ک¬—¼ٌ⁴‌¨ا£–ك›D“µھ—⹫戼㹲਍⼼㹰਍⼼潦瑮ാ㰊牢㰾ہخ㰾ہخ㰾ہخ㰾ہخ㰾ہخാ㰊潦瑮挠汯牯∽㠣㠰㠰∰猠穩㵥¢ç•‘Wة¢∽慔潨慭㸢‍ڈ㰾㹢—èجُ³±¬›قوè‏ئصêô‘\کNœ«س³êôم³›ؤœ§ھ› 
                          ¹¬‹êô㩳⼼㹢⼼㹰਍瀼䜾œ£ °¬‹œ§⁧”²°d °›’R⹣潣㱭‍„ാ㰊㹰湁牵条䴮¬“‘` —»»ن½’«ن´‘ù㹲਍⌠氦㭴⌠⸵⸱‱浳灴㔻〵㔠ㄮㄮ删卅䱏䕖⹒䑁⹒敒楣买瑯潆湵㭤ا‎¬کس³®ڈ“³ëü㭴⌠䵓偔㰣‍„ാ㰊㹰湁牤⹥敓畱湩牀换浣挮浯戼㹲਍⌠氦㭴⌠⸵⸱‱浳灴㔻〵㔠ㄮㄮ删卅䱏䕖
                          ⹒䑁⹒敒楣买瑯潆湵㭤ا‎¬کس³®ڈ“³ëü㭴⌠䵓偔㰣‍„ാ㰊㹰扁楨慮⹶獁橩䁡’Rµ·⹭潣㱭ہخാ ☣瑬※㔣ㄮㄮ猠瑭㭰㔵،ë⸵⸱‱䕒体噌剅䄮„q¹خ’ج‍¹‌‡䙴®ڈ“³،ù³±⁴ءتœ±♤瑧※匣呍⍐⼼㹰਍瀼伾楲楧慮⁬敭獳条⁥”«“© 
                          °㩳⼼㹰਍瀼敲刾捥楥敶㩤س³نû⁭硭⸳扲⹣潣⁭ㄨ⸰〲⸸㌱⸶⤵戠⁹塓䍓㑍㄰昮⹧扲⹣潣൭ ㄨ⸰〲⸸㤱⸲ㄴ
                          楷桴䴠قونû‌¤¬گ½³…ش⁐敓癲牥椠⁤㐱㌮ㄮ㐷ㄮ※敗Ɽ㐠䨠湵㈠㄰ഴ 㜱㐺㨳㤲ⴠ㐰〰਍ⵘ牉湯潐瑲䄭¬—⵩灓浡䘭مéصûاأ㩤¬_î´൥堊䤭نû‚آêô⵴湁楴匭慰⵭敒畳瑬›ڑM䉙䑁⌦㌴医ㅪ䕎䤶癥䝮獤㉢桊䅢䩄±’䈴شت䉅¶ç䩷਍ⵘ牉湯潐瑲䄭㩖䔠…]µئ‌œ㭳㵩½¹‌¥㭴⸴㠹㤬㔷ㄬ㤳ㄲㄸ〲
                          ☰畱瑯㬻ഠ †㵤焦潵㭴“µ❦猿慣❮〲ⰸㄲ☷畱瑯㬻㵡焦潵㭴㠱〳㐲㠹☳畱瑯഻堊匭剂㩓㔠㘮਍敒散癩摥›êَن´®_ڑm³±œ³⠠䕈佌攠慳⸲慭歲瑥硡獥⹳灩浨⹸潣⥭⠠㙛⸸㌲⸲㌱⸵㜱崵ഩ 戠⁹浶㍸爮换挮浯眠瑩⁨ط¦…ش⽐䱔⽓䍒ⴴ䡓㭁〠‴畊⁮〲㐱ㄠ㨷㌴ㄺ‵〭〴ര堊䤭نû‚آêô⵴噁›㵅‌Œ—Iâ´—
                          â☽畱瑯㐻㤮ⰸ㜹ⰵ㌱㈹㐱㈵〰焦潵㭴،ù਍†搠☽畱瑯瀻晤㼧’صœں¢ى㠰㈬㜱½¹‌¥㭴گô☽畱瑯ㄻ〶¤¨㠷焦潵㭴਍敒散癩摥›êَن´®_ڑm³±œ³⠠䕈佌挠灲敳浣楡桬ぴ⸲佃偒剏呁⹅佌䅃⥌⠠㉛㐰ㄮ㠲㔮⸲崰ഩ 戠⁹獥㉡洮ظہ敫慴數獳椮桰硭挮浯眠瑩⁨ط¦…ش⽐䱔⽓䕁ㅓ㠲匭䅈،°㔰䨠湵㈠㄰ഴ ㈰
                          㐺㨱㠵☠㐣㬳㔰〰਍敒散癩摥›êَن´‍u“·”²ن½ھ›·َぢ‱ㄨ⸰〴㈮㌵㌮⤰戠⁹剃卐䍅䅍䱉呈㈰䌮„y×ô䅒䕔䰮䍏䱁਍⠠〱㐮⸰ㄱ⸲㔱⤴眠瑩⁨—ٌ ®â´¾°⁴䵓‚½³ °”´⁲ؤ¦ㄠ⸴⸳㜱⸴㬱圠摥‬‴畊⁮〲㐱਍ㄠ㨷ㄴ㔺،ا〭〴ര琊牨慥ⵤ湩敤㩸䄠♣㐣㬳偁䙡つ䵨䭏䕋半焹丹䍃‹C䜲…و㵑ഽ吊
                          牨慥ⵤ潔楰㩣䴠⁁䝈吠慲敤删捥灡〠⼶㐰㈯㄰ഴ䘊潲㩭☠瑬䴻ؤµë¸䅴”µ«A›µؤµë¸‘b”µ«A’«ن´ëü㭴਍潔ഺ䌊㩃☠瑬吻慲敤敒慣䑰ک@µ…›µؤµë¸‘b”µ«A’«ن´ëü㭴਍畓橢捥㩴䴠⁁䝈吠慲敤删捥灡〠⼶㐰㈯㄰ഴ䐊瑡㩥ˆL“‬‴畊⁮〲㐱ㄠ㨷〴㐺‰〭〴ര䴊獥慳敧䤭㩄☠瑬䔻㘶㌹ぃ
                          ㌸㌲㐳㜲䈴䘸䕃㈲㥃䐶㉂䄳䀸牐摯捵楴湯䰮’زخغëü㭴਍䥍䕍嘭牥楳湯›⸱ര䌊湯整瑮吭灹㩥›£›NکNخ؟¬ڑ›³چ“഻ऊ潢湵慤祲☽畱瑯ⴻⴭ㴭也硥側牡彴〰弰〰㔰た䌱㡆㄰⹃䄱〵㑂〵焦潵㭴਍ⵘ慍汩牥›—ٌ ®â´¾°⁴䑃⁏潦⁲é¥“³²J⁳〲〰਍潃瑮湥⵴汃獡㩳®_œ®ح¦œ«صû¬—’ھ‘[«
                          Aھ—›³ھ—‘a”ھ਍浉潰瑲湡散›³±›حخغ਍牐潩楲祴›³±›حخغ਍ⵘ楍敭䱏㩅‚‹نû®‡ة¢⁤祂䴠قونû‌¤¬گ䴠浩佥䕌嘠⸶〰㌮㤷⸰㤴㌱਍敒畴湲倭瑡㩨䴠牡敫䅴”µ«A›µؤµë¸‘b”µ«A’«ن´਍⼼牰㹥਍⼼潦瑮ാ㰊戯摯㹹਍⼼瑨汭

Comment: Could you paste some of the stuff you can't parse?

Comment: @JoeRod Do the non delivery report messages show up as Chinese when viewed in Outlook before they've been accessed by your script?  In my case I have an Outlook addin that tries to view the body of the non delivery reports.  When the addin is loaded, the body of the reports is Chinese but when the addin is not loaded, the non delivery report bodies show up normally

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a bug in Outlook 2013. See:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/when-forwarding-or-replying-to-emails-the-text/61280c0d-0fd6-48cf-9318-184ee3e83da9

In my case I got the strange gibberish when trying to view the body of a non delivery report from an Outlook 2013 addin (not such which version of Exchange we're using).  But when the addin is disabled, the body of the non-delivery report shows up just fine.